# Call a method property in view from a class?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

From the class `PCSS.Common.Configuration.ConfigurationFunctions` I need to call the method property `var qe = new QueryExpression("pcs_configurationitem");` in my view.

var qe = new QueryExpression("pcs_configurationitem"); is in a string method

below is the code of var qe in a string, and I need to call pcs_configurationitem in view.

```
public static string GetString(string key, IOrganizationService service)
{
    var qe = new QueryExpression("pcs_configurationitem"); //want this in view
    qe.Criteria.AddCondition(new ConditionExpression("pcs_name", ConditionOperator.Equal, key));
    qe.Criteria.AddCondition(new ConditionExpression("pcs_valuetype", ConditionOperator.Equal, (int)ConfigItemType.String));
    qe.Criteria.AddCondition(new ConditionExpression("pcs_stringvalue", ConditionOperator.NotNull));
    qe.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(new string[] { "pcs_stringvalue" });
    var results = service.RetrieveMultiple(qe);
    if (results.Entities.Count == 0) throw new Exception("No value of this type found for key " + key);
    return (results[0].GetAttributeValue<string>("pcs_stringvalue"));
}
```

Im trying to do something like below to call it in my view.

```
<span title="Feedback is not suppored more than @ConfigurationFunctions.("pcs_configurationitem") days after closing the enquiry.">`</span>`
```

However this is not working, please advise.

Comment: `ConfigurationFunctions.("pcs_configurationitem")` is not valid C# syntax, whether in Razor or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put some code at the top of your page:

```
@model MyModel
@{
  var qe = new QueryExpression("pcs_configurationitem"); 
}
```

Then down in your markup:

```
<span title="Feedback is not suppored more than @qe days after closing the enquiry."></span>
```

You may need to add a `@using` directive at the top to reference the appropriate namespace for `QueryExpression`.